# Sum Column in R Studio with Alphabetical Name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I cannot successfully sum a column in R Studio from a database in SQL. I keep getting the error "Error in FUN: only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables".

Currently, I have:

```
newObject <- dataFrame %>% sum("COLUMN NAME", na.rm = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to pipe the entire `dataFrame` object into the `sum` function.

In essence, you're trying this:

```
newObject <- sum(dataFrame, "COLUMN NAME", na.rm = FALSE)
```

That isn't working because some of the values in your `dataFrame` are character. And if they aren't `"COLUMN NAME"` at the very least is a character string.

You might be looking for `summarise`, but other possibilities may be `transmute` or `mutate`:

```
mtcars %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(mpg, na.rm= FALSE))
#    Sum
#1 642.9

mtcars %>%
  transmute(Sum = sum(mpg, na.rm=FALSE))
#     Sum
#1  642.9
#2  642.9
#...

mtcars %>%
  mutate(Sum = sum(mpg, na.rm= FALSE))
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   Sum
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 642.9
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 642.9
#...
```

Here `mpg` is the name of a column in `mtcars`. You can replace that with your column name, but without quotes.

Comment: Just one clarification question- "Sum" is a created variable, correct? When I give it a variable name and attempt to use that variable it says the object is not found.

Comment: All of these methods create a new column in the original data. Additionally, remember that if you want to save the new data, you have to assign it back somewhere as you did in your question `newObject <-`. So you could find the result of `newObject <- mtcars %>%  summarise(Sum = sum(mpg, na.rm= FALSE))` in `newObject$Sum`.